# icsharpcode.sharpziplib limitation

Tags: c#, sharpziplib

I am using the library to read a zip file. The zip contains about 200,000 files.
Half of them with .txt extension and half of them with .csv extension.

However, when I use the following code to extract them,

```
var fs = File.OpenRead(_archiveName);
var _zipFile = new ZipFile(fs);

var csvs = (from ZipEntry zipEntry in _zipFile
                    where Path.GetExtension(zipEntry.Name) == ".csv"                    select zipEntry).ToDictionary(
                        z => GenerateBookName(extension, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(z.Name)), z => z );
```

The number of items in csvs dictionaires are only about 500 keyvalue pairs.

Is there a limitation of the library?

Thanks

Comment: Could it be a casing issue? Are all your filename extensions in lowercase?

Comment: They are all lower case.